# .Net Core 2.2 and IIS Session Data

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, iis

I'm trying to deploy a .NET Core 2.2 app on IIS. The IIS server is configured for SSO with ADFS (SAML). That is working, and after successful authentication IIS stores the user's login attributes as session variables and uses a cookie for session id.

When I deploy a simple ASPX template to display the attributes, it works fine:

```
<% @ Page Language="C#" %>
<%
Response.Write("<h3>Session Variables</h3>");
Response.Write("User Id = " + Request["userId"] + "<br>");
Response.Write("Email = " + Request["email"] + "<br>");
%>
```

That code correctly displays the expected session attributes. However, when I deploy my .Net Core 2.2 application as an In-Process application to IIS. I'm unable to see those session attributes. Here is how I'm attempting to access the session variables:

```
_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.HttpContext.Session.GetString("userId"); <-- Returns Null
```

And in fact, I'm not getting ANY session variables at all:

```
_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.HttpContext.Session.Keys.Count().ToString(); <-- Returns 0
```

Am I able to access Session variables and Server variables set by IIS with .Net Core even though I'm deploying as "In-Process"? (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/?view=aspnetcore-2.2#in-process-hosting-model)

Here is the webconfig:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\MyApp.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="InProcess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
    <system.web>
        <identity impersonate="false" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

-- EDIT - Adding Startup --

```
using cFTE_Services.Repositories;
using cFTE_Services.Services;
using Serilog;

namespace cFTEServices
{
    using System;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Cors.Internal;
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
    using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger;

    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {

            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
            services.AddSession(options => { options.Cookie.IsEssential = true; });
            services.AddMvc(
                config => {
                    config.Filters.Add(new CorsAuthorizationFilterFactory("CorsPolicy"));
                    config.Filters.Add(new AllowAnonymousFilter());
                }
            ).SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

            var corsDomains = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("CORS_DOMAINS")?.Split(",");
            services.AddCors(
                options => {
                    options.AddPolicy(
                        "CorsPolicy",
                        builder => builder
                            .WithOrigins(corsDomains)
                            .AllowAnyMethod()
                            .AllowAnyHeader()
                            .AllowCredentials()
                    );
                }
            );


            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
            services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options => 
            {
                options.AutomaticAuthentication = false;
            });

            //Services
            services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();

            services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerDoc("v1",
                    new Info
                    {
                        Title = "My App",
                        Version = "v1"
                    });
            });
            Log.Warning("Config services complete.");
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseDefaultFiles();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseSwagger(); 
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "cFTE API v1");
            });
            app.UseSession();
            app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you include your `Startup` class please?

Comment: Thanks, I just updated

Comment: It's not clear from your question, but it looks as though you've got an ASP.NET session store that you're attempting to use in ASP.NET Core. The two cannot natively communicate. Sessions are stored differently and encrypted differently. The cookie with the session id is also encrypted differently, and while you can get around *that*, you can't get around the differences in server-side storage. Long and short, this is a no-go.

Comment: @ChrisPratt one thought I had was to use an external SQL database to store ASP.NET session data and then just run SQL query against the database to retrieve the session variables in my .Net Core app?

Comment: That won't work because the session data is encrypted in a way you will not be able to decrypt outside of the ASP.NET application. You could expose what essentially amounts to a session API with endpoints that simply either set or get session data on the ASP.NET side. Then, you can use a service in ASP.NET Core with a typed client (`IHttpClientFactory`) that connects to those endpoints to set and get session data, and use that in place of `Session`.

Comment: Would I still be able to deploy the .Net Core app as "In Process"? Or do I essentially have 2 apps now?