# How to use the session state config in the Asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I created a web application using ASP.Net MVC 5.
Now I am going to migrate this project to ASP.Net Core and serve it.

Currently, I am using the session server separately. And the Web.config setting is as shown below:

```
<sessionState mode="StateServer" stateConnectionString="tcpip=1.1.1:45000" timeout="20" />
```

How would I set it up with ASP.Net Core?

Comment: Try to configure in ConfigureServices. App process can be configured in web.config, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57716069/net-core-2-2-and-iis-session-data , docs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.1#session-state

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, if you want to use sql server as the session stat provider, you should set the SQL Server distributed cache firstly in asp.net core and then configure the session.

More details, you could refer to below steps:

1.Distributed SQL Server Cache

Create a table in SQL Server by running the sql-cache create command. Provide the SQL Server instance (Data Source), database (Initial Catalog), schema (for example, dbo), and table name (for example, TestCache):

```
dotnet sql-cache create "Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=DistCache;Integrated Security=True;" dbo TestCache
```

2.Add below codes into configure service:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)  
    {  
services.AddDistributedSqlServerCache(options =>
{
    options.ConnectionString = 
        _config["DistCache_ConnectionString"];
    options.SchemaName = "dbo";
    options.TableName = "TestCache";
}); 
          
        services.AddSession(options => {   
            options.CookieName = "Test.Session";  
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);   
        });  
          
          
        services.AddMvc();  
    }
```